# Problems with SnapShotReadyCallback and ProgressDialog

Tags: android, google-maps

Trying to get a snapshot of the Google Maps I have up. I have the code below:

```
    public class CaptureMapScreen extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        Log.d("pre","pre-execute");
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WalkStarted.this, "Uploading",
                "Please wait...");

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                bitmap = snapshot;
                try {
                    Log.d("storage", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(save_loc);

                    // above "/mnt ..... png" => is a storage path (where image will be stored) + name of image you can customize as per your Requirement

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    UploadImageClass uim = new UploadImageClass();
                    int response = 0;
                    try {
                        response = uim.execute(save_loc).get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println("RES : " + response);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        mMap.snapshot(callback);
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the logs, I see

```
12-19 07:40:46.731  13516-13516/ly.leash.Leashly D/ID﹕ 2131361924
12-19 07:40:46.731  13516-13516/ly.leash.Leashly D/pre﹕ pre-execute
12-19 07:40:46.951  13516-13516/ly.leash.Leashly D/storage﹕ /storage/emulated/0
12-19 07:40:52.231  13516-13932/ly.leash.Leashly I/uploadFile﹕ HTTP Response is : OK: 200
12-19 07:40:52.231  13516-13516/ly.leash.Leashly I/System.out﹕ RES : 200
12-19 07:40:52.231  13516-13516/ly.leash.Leashly I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 338 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

The server response stuff is from my UploadImageClass(another AsyncTask). So for whatever reason, I cannot seem to get the ProgressDialog to come up at the beginning of this activity. It shows up at the end briefly and disappears. I can obviously guess/see that the UI is getting locked, but I don't see where, since this is all background stuff.

Occasionally this works as I expect it to, and the ProgressDialog comes up, but generally it doesn't work as intended.

Edit: I added a

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String args)
    {
        Log.d("post","post-execute2");

    }
```

This also prints before the ProgressDialog is shown

Edit2:

My OnClick that starts this event ONLY starts this event. No other calls going on after the Asynctask that is launched above. I'm thinking maybe the Google Maps Api is screwing it up? Maybe the onLocationChanged() calls or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call the CaptureMapScreen AsyncTask? You could probably show your dialog before you execute your asyncTask not inside your onPreExecute() method.

For example:

```
  dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WalkStarted.this, "Uploading",
                "Please wait...");
  CaptureMapScreen captureMapScreenTask = new GetBlogPostsTask();
  captureMapScreenTask.execute();
```